# Как записать хеш из yaml файла в переменную?

Tags: ruby, yaml

У меня есть yml файл. Я хочу открыть его и записать в переменную.
Я пытаюсь сделать так, но этот код не работает :(
Внутри файла {"type"=>"dog", "name"=>"Richi"}

```rb
require "yaml"
hash = YAML.load_file("bd.yml")
puts hash
#(bd.yml): did not find expected ',' or '}' while parsing a flow mapping at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формат файла описан в статье: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML